# How can I enable the console in Survival mode?

Tags: fallout-4

The console is fully disabled when playing on a Survival mode save (from the beta). There is no way to enable it I've seen, either from the .ini settings or by changing the keyboard bindings or even the launch options. It seems that the console is only disabled in Survival mode -- in Normal difficulties the console is available and usable.

How can I re-enable the console in Survival mode?

To note, the Fallout 4 PC version is considerably very buggy. There are numerous spots where players can get stuck; console commands make getting out of these "traps" possible. Without console commands, it may be possible to get stuck and never get out.

Comment: Ugh. A Bethesda game without console access. A fate worse than Oblivion.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Before you jump to conclusions, the game specifically has the console disabled when in a Survival mode state; when in a normal game the console is available. It seems to only pertain to Survival mode

Comment: @skully I understand the question. But any Bethesda game without `tcl` is going to involve lots of getting stuck in things.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yeah, it's actually why I asked the question. I got stuck wayyyy too many times so if it happened to me in Survival I would be completely screwd over

Comment: [Public beta content is on topic per meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)

Comment: Can we at least indicate in the question that it's about the beta? Things change between betas and full releases.

Comment: @skully That's not true. Every Xbox One, PS4, and PC user who hasn't opted into the beta has a survival mode already. It's the hardest difficulty that came with the game. Any correct answer they give is incorrect for the beta you're playing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

[A mod has been released](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/11663/?) that lets you enable survival mode multiple times. There is no .esp file, so no workaround is needed to load the mod. Now you can disable survival mode, use the console, and then re-enable survival. Note that all the survival stats (hunger, thirst, etc) will be reset.

---

Bethesda has disabled the console for the beta Survival mode as can be seen [here](https://community.bethesda.net/thread/3321) and [here (from an official Bethesda source)](https://community.bethesda.net/thread/2952).

<strike>There is currently no known workaround</strike>. Since it is disabled intentionally as a feature to prevent cheating, it is likely hard-coded and not changeable through modifying config files, as that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I know they disabled it, what I'm looking for is a bypass by modifying some part of the configuration settings to enable the console.

Comment: @skully Sorry yeah, I didn't actually answer the question. The fact that it is disabled to prevent cheating suggests that it wouldn't be possible to change this, at least without mods (which are currently disabled).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable mods and / or a few console commands **here's how**!

**http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/11479/?**

**(Just read the description on the page and u can have mods on survival mode!)**

Comment: This doesn't allow you to use the console in-game, it only lets you pass console commands when the game loads. It can be used to load mods but won't help if you get stuck, which is what the question asks.

Answer (score -1):

During survival mode there is no way to enable the console...

Comment: Can you explain why or state your sources you used to figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/11834/?tab=13&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Ffallout4%2Fajax%2Fmodgraph%2F%3Fid%3D11834&pUp=1

Works beautifully, simply re-enables the console no strings attached.

Comment: why is this being downvoted? It's a viable solution.